# Digital ocean app not rendering SSR (Server Side Rendering)

Tags: angular, digital-ocean, server-side-rendering

I have an angular app and I am trying out Digital Ocean and I cannot get SSR to work. When I run the same script locally it works (I can view the page source and my content is there).

Here is my build command:

```json
"build:ssr:website-test": "ng build --prod && ng run website-test:server:production"
```

and here is my run command:

```json
"serve:ssr": "node dist/website-test/server/main.js",
```

The port is set to 8080. Is there something else I need to set to get this to work?

Also, if it helps, the build is coming from my GitLab repo.

I am running my `getRequest()` on `ngOnInit`. Could it be a timing issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well it was something stupid on my end. I forgot to set the real endpoint and was still using localhost. Everything is working as expected now.